# How to draw labeled parallel arrows in commutative diagram with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw labeled parallel arrow in commutative diagram with TikZ, I searched on google and Tex Stackexchange, however, I found only the method to draw parallel arrow by `transform canvas` only, I tried to add the labeled but it failed.

Here is my picture:

[image]

I want to label a map from `$\mathfrak{P}=\bigoplus_{i\inI}\mathfrak{P_{i}}$` to `$\mathfrak{P_{i}}$ and from $\mathfrak{P_{i}}$` to `$\mathfrak{P}=\bigoplus_{i\inI}\mathfrak{P_{i}}$`, i.e the arrows of the square.

Here is the code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.8cm, auto]
\node (P) {$\mathfrak{P}=\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathfrak{P_{i}}$};
\node(Q)[right of=P] {$\mathfrak{P_{j}}$};
\node (B) [below of=P] {$\mathfrak{B}$};
\node (C) [right of=B] {$\mathfrak{C}$};
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=0.5ex},->] (P) - -(Q);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-0.5ex},->](Q) -- (P); 
\draw[->](Q) to node {$a$}(B);
\draw[->](Q) to node {$a$}(C);
\draw[->] (P) to node {$\pi_{j}$} (B);
\draw[->] (B) to node {$\psi$} (C);
\draw[->, dashed] (Q) to node [swap] {$g$} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @percusse: Thank you for helping me editing my post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are your labeled lines.

There are other ways to shift nodes but IMO the `transform canvas` is the most direct, so you are doing fine for that aspect.

To label a line, you can add a node command at the end of the line specification. The label may be placed `above` or `below` and you can specify where along the line with keywords such as `midway` or the more general `pos=<fraction along line>`. I also shifted the diagonal lines so that they may both be seen (since one was dashed).

I added a macro to simplify the shifting of the diagonal lines.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.8cm, auto]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{0.3ex}

\node (P) {$\mathfrak{P}=\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathfrak{P_{i}}$};
\node(Q)[right of=P] {$\mathfrak{P_{j}}$};
\node (B) [below of=P] {$\mathfrak{B}$};
\node (C) [right of=B] {$\mathfrak{C}$};

\draw[transform canvas={yshift=0.5ex},->] (P) --(Q) node[above,midway] {\tiny top};
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-0.5ex},->](Q) -- (P) node[below,midway] {\tiny bottom}; 
\draw[->](Q) to node {$a$}(C);
\draw[->] (P) to node[swap] {$\pi_{j}$} (B);
\draw[->,dashed] (B) to node {$\psi$} (C);

\draw[->,transform canvas={xshift=-\shift,yshift=\shift}](Q) to node {$a$}(B);
\draw[->, dashed,transform canvas={xshift=\shift,yshift=-\shift}] (Q) to node[swap] {$g$} (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `([yshift=...]P)--([yshift=...]Q)` is also an option.

Comment: @percusse: you are correct, but I think that that method is more appropriate when you are shifting each point by a different amount.

Comment: With `transform canvas` one runs into two problems (not in this case, though): the bounding box is not correct, and any positions saved whilst under the influence will not be correct (try labelling the `top` to see).  However, when I tried percusse's method, I got strange results.  To get the right result, I had to add the anchor: `([yshift=2.5ex]P.east) -- ([yshift=2.5ex]Q.west)`.

Comment: I agree with Andrew for `transform canvas`. This option is sometimes dangerous (see the pgfmanual). Now `([yshift=...]P)--([yshift=...]Q)` (remark from percusse) is wrong. You need to use `P.east` and `Q.west`. But for the arrow between Q and C, `transform canvas` is useful to get something elegant (similar arrows)

Comment: @AndrewStacey xshift and yshift works with coordinates

Comment: @AndrewStacey Indeed, I forgot the anchors. I guess I was too fast to post the comment without compiling anything.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps to clarify some points.

1) First `([yshift=...]P)--([yshift=...]Q)` does not work. 
Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(A) at (0,0) {A};   \node(B) at (5,0) {B};
   \draw[green] (A) -- (B);
   \draw [yellow,yshift=.5 cm] (0,0) -- (5,0);
   \draw[blue,yshift=1 cm] (A) -- (B); %problem
   \draw[red] ([yshift=1 cm]A) -- ([yshift=1 cm]B);  %problem
   \draw[magenta] ([yshift=1 cm]A.east) -- ([yshift=1 cm]B.west);     
\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate(A) at (0,0) ;   \coordinate(B) at (5,0);
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \draw[red] ([yshift=.5 cm]A) -- ([yshift=.5 cm]B);  %fine 
  \draw[blue,yshift=1 cm] (A) -- (B); %problem    
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

2) About `transform canvas`

> Canvas transformations should be used with great care. In most
>   circumstances you do not want line widths to change in a picture as
>   this creates visual inconsistency. Just as important, when you use
>   canvas transformations pgf loses track of positions of nodes and of
>   picture sizes since it does not take the effect of canvas
>   transformations into account when it computes coordinates of nodes (do
>   not, however, rely on this; it may change in the future). Finally,
>   note that a canvas transformation always applies to a path as a whole,
>   it is not possible (as for coordinate transformations) to use
>   different transformations in different parts of a path. In short, you
>   should not use canvas transformations unless you really know what you
>   are doing.

I think it's better to avoid it

3) I remove `right of` etc. because i like to scale my pictures when it's necessary

`right of` seems to be more concise but you need to fix `node distance=...` and to write 
`right of=P` `at (5,0)` is more concise or `--++(5,0)``

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=2]

\node (P) at (0,0)  {$\mathfrak{P}=\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathfrak{P_{i}}$};
\node (Q) at (3,0)  {$\mathfrak{P_{j}}$};
\node (B) at (0,-3) {$\mathfrak{B}$};
\node (C) at (3,-3) {$\mathfrak{C}$};    


\draw[->] ([yshift =  .3ex]P.east)  --  node[above] {\tiny top}     
          ([yshift =  .3ex]Q.west) ;
\draw[<-] ([yshift = -.3ex]P.east) --  node[below] {\tiny bottom}  
          ([yshift = -.3ex]Q.west); 
\draw[->](Q) to node {$a$}(C);
\draw[->] (P) to node[swap] {$\pi_{j}$} (B);
\draw[->,dashed] (B) to node {$\psi$} (C);  

\draw[->]    ( Q.south west)  -- node[above] {$a$}
             ( B.north east) ; 

\draw[->,dashed] ([xshift= 0.2ex ,yshift = - 0.3ex ] Q.south west) -- node[below] {$g$} 
                 ([xshift=  0.2ex ,yshift = - 0.3ex ]B.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a strange output. I learned yet another subtle detail thanks to you.

Comment: There are a lot of strange outputs and subtle details with TeX and TikZ ! With my old neurons, I forget many of these details every day.

Answer (score 7):

You might also want to have a look at the rather new package [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

Its command `\arrow` has a mandatory argument identifying the direction, e.g. `r` for “right”. It also has an optional argument to specify TikZ options like `transform canvas`. It also has further argument pairs (optional and “mandatory” ) for labels.

- An arrow pointing right: `\arrow{r}`
- An arrow pointing right with label above: `\arrow{r}{label}`
- An arrow pointing right with label below: `\arrow{r}[swap]{label}`
- An arrow pointing right and shifted: `\arrow[transform canvas={yshift=.5ex}]{r}`

Here's a complete try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3cm,column sep=2.5cm]
   \mathfrak{P}=\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathfrak{P_{i}}
     \arrow[transform canvas={yshift=.5ex}]{r}
     \arrow[transform canvas={yshift=-.5ex},leftarrow]{r}
     \arrow{d}[swap]{\pi_{j}}
 & \mathfrak{P_{j}}
     \arrow{d}{a}
     \arrow[transform canvas={yshift=.3ex,xshift=-.3ex}]{ld}[swap]{g}
     \arrow[transform canvas={yshift=-0.3ex,xshift=.3ex},dashed]{ld}{a} \\
     \mathfrak{B}
     \arrow{r}{\psi}
 & \mathfrak{C}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]