# Commutative diagram with parallel arrows in opposite direction

Tags: amsmath, arrows, commutative-diagrams

I have a diagram of the following form, written with the package `amscd`:

```
\begin{align*}
 \begin{CD}
  W @>\phi>> X \\
  @V{a}V{b}V  @V{c}V{d}V \\
  Y @>\phi>> Z \\
 \end{CD}
\end{align*}
```

It want the vertical arrows to be parallel arrows in opposite direction, such that `a` and `c` point downwards and `b` and `d` point upwards. (For those who understand the terms, it is about an isomorphism between chain complexes.)

To my best knowledge, `amscd` does not provide these features. Can you show me a piece of code that provides this functionality and is similarly easy to use?

Comment: Do [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48216/5049) and its answers help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all don't use `align*` for a single object and prefer `equation*`.

Simple commutative diagrams with the CD environment can have arrows pointing

- right

  ```
  @>>>
  ```
- left

  ```
  @<<<
  ```
- down

  ```
  @VVV
  ```
- up

  ```
  @AAA
  ```
- double stem, no arrow head

  ```
  @=
  ```
- nothing (for filling blanks)

  ```
  @.
  ```

However `CD` doesn't allow for "double arrows" and you have to go to a more specialized package. For instance `xy`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix{
   W \ar[r]^{\phi} \ar@<-2pt>[d]_{a} & X \ar@<-2pt>[d]_{c} \\
   Y\ar@<-2pt>[u]_{b} \ar[r]^{\phi} & Z \ar@<-2pt>[u]_{d}
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for this answer! It helped me solve the last diagram issue that I had here:

Answer (score 3):

In addition to egregs answer, one could use the package `tikz-cd` for this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}     
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
W \arrow{r}{\phi} \arrow[shift right, swap]{d}{a}& X \arrow[shift right, swap]{d}{c}\\
Y \arrow{r}{\phi} \arrow[shift right, swap]{u}{b} & Z \arrow[shift right, swap]{u}{d}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess that `tikz-cd` wasn't available at the time of my answer (or it was still too preliminary).