# Blank or no arrow in a commutative diagram

Tags: arrows, commutative-diagrams

I learned from [this nice post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49116/commutative-diagram-with-parallel-arrows-in-opposite-direction/49161#49161) that a commutative diagram with the CD environment can have arrows pointing and their commands:

- right

  ```
  @>>>
  ```
- left

  ```
  @<<<
  ```
- down

  ```
  @VVV
  ```
- up

  ```
  @AAA
  ```

**Question**: what is the case that if I just like to keep a blank spacing without arrow? What is the command?

Comment: A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) please!

Comment: excuse me, this is just asking a command or function...

Comment: May I suggest that you use the packages xypic or tikz-cd for drawing commutative diagrams? They have somewhat intuitive syntax... But, I will post an answer too... :-)

Comment: Thanks kan, a similar but not the same issue , but with MWE. See [the new post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180685/commutative-diagram-with-blank-spacing-and-crossing-layer-arrows)

Comment: You don't have to excuse yourself. Just post some compilable code next time; that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is taken verbatim from Milne's [notes](http://www.jmilne.org/not/Mamscd.pdf) on `amscd` package:

Here is the MWE showing all the possible arrows in the `amscd` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amscd}
\begin{document}
$\begin{CD}
A @<<< B @>>> C\\
@. @| @AAA\\
@. D @= E
\end{CD}$
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: output.png]

In particular, the complete list of arrows is:

- right

  ```
  @>>>
  ```
- left

  ```
  @<<<
  ```
- down

  ```
  @VVV
  ```
- up

  ```
  @AAA
  ```
- horizontal equals to

  ```
  @=
  ```
- vertical equals to

  ```
  @|
  ```
- empty arrow

  ```
  @.
  ```

PS: You'd probably appreciate my comment under your question post if that is coming from someone with more experience, so please see Milne's [Guide to Commutative Diagram Packages](http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html) for some words about his personal experience.

Comment: I see, Kan, thanks, it is pretty clear! +1.