# Commutative diagram with blank spacing and crossing-layer arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, amsmath, arrows, tikz-cd

Related to [a previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180683/blank-or-no-arrow-in-a-commutative-diagram), now pardon me to go to a specific example,

here is my output

[image]

and my Minimum Working Environment

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}
\begin{document}



$$
\begin{CD}
1+1 @>>> 2+1 @>>> 3+1 @>>> \dots @>>> d+1 \dots\\
12 @<<< 123 @<<< 1234 @<<< \dots @<<< 123(d+1)\\
@| @| @|\\
 @>>> xy  @<<< xyz @<<<
\end{CD}
$$


\end{document}
```

> **Question**: what I wish is that the similar diagram as above: 
>   but having the following conditions:
>
> (i) all the **leftarrow @>>> removed**, but keeps the same spacing as before.
>
> (ii) all the down equal line removed @| removed, but the same (or smilier) spacing
>
> (iii) connecting xyz to 12 from the right to the left arrow (<---)

**(iii) may be challenging, so it is fine to neglect this (iii), and  your reply on (i)(ii) still count as an answer.**

Thank you, any comment is welcome and helpful! :)

Comment: You could have waited for my answer on the previous post: I did promise to write an answer! Does my answer in that post help you with this one? I think all you need to is replace by `@.` and that is it! Edit: I don't think you can do slant arrows in AMSCD package! I am writing a quick tikz-cd answer to this question!

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd), here is a `tikz-cd` answer:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
1+1 & 2+1       & 3+1        & \cdots       & d + 1 \\
12  & 123 \ar{l}& 1234 \ar{l}& \cdots \ar{l}& 123 \dots (d+1) \ar{l}\\
    & xy \ar{ul}& xyz  \ar{l}& \ar{l}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

**The output:**

[image: mwe2.png]

---

**Update:** Here is an answer with `xypic` as you asked in the comments:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix{
1+1 & 2+1       & 3+1        & \dots        & d + 1 \\
12  & 123 \ar[l]& 1234 \ar[l]& \cdots \ar[l]& 123 \dots (d+1) \ar[l]\\
    & xy \ar[ul]& xyz  \ar[l]& \ar[l]
}$
\end{document}
```

**The Output:**

[image: mwe3]

Comment: @ Kan, thanks, it is pretty clear! +1.

Comment: but excuse me what if I also need an arrow from xyz to 12. Not just xy to 12?

Comment: also, I cannot compile it successfully, via \documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix,amsart]{revtex4}

Comment: I could not compile it even using your set-up:

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

Comment: @Idear, what is the error message: something like missing package? It would help if you tell me the version of TeXLive or MikTeX that you may be using?

Comment: Could one use \xymatrix{} instead, will that also work? If you know \xymatrix{}, that can count as a separate answer. :)

Comment: OK, let me try... regarding your other question about arrows, the general rule is, if you want an arrow, the direction is specified by `u, d, r, l` with their obvious meanings. And, you can use a combination of them like I did: so, `llu` would be an answer to your question; left, left, up is the instruction you would tell xyz if (s)he wanted to 12. Any other valid instruction works too :-)

Comment: @Idear See my updated answer!