# arrows in diagrams with beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How can I make this with LaTeX in `beamer` (I have problems with the arrows) ?

[image]

I only have this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ node distance = 8.1 mm and 6 mm, > = stealth', every node/.style = {circle, draw=pink!30!black, fill=pink!30, minimum size=8mm} ]
\node (b) {\tiny A};
\node (a) [below right=of b] {{\tiny C}};
\node (c) [above right=of a] {{\tiny B}};
\node (d) [below right=of c] {{\tiny D}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have only problems with the arrows, can you show what you have for the rest?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question. In comments linebreaks etc are lost and the code becomes a mess.

Comment: Please don't use comments for adding code like that, rather edit your question. I extended the code snippet to a complete MWE as @samcarter asked for, please modify it if there is anything else needed.

Comment: Some related posts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48216/how-to-draw-labeled-parallel-arrows-in-commutative-diagram-with-tikz and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205262/586

Comment: @tarl, added code doesn't reflect your image ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two versions with help of library `automata`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten < =  1mm, shorten > = 1mm,
node distance = 33mm, on grid, auto,
every path/.style = {bend left, -Latex}
                    ]
\node[state] (A) {A};
\node[state] (B) [right=of A] {B};
\node[state] (C) [below=of A] {C};
\node[state] (D) [right=of C] {D};
%
\path[->]   (A) edge ["e"] (B)
            (B) edge        (D)
            (D) edge        (C)
            (C) edge ["h"] (A)
%
            (A) edge        (C)
            (C) edge        (D)
            (D) edge ["g"] (B)
            (B) edge ["f"] (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten < =  1mm, shorten > = 1mm,
node distance = 33mm, on grid, auto,
every path/.style = {-Latex},
sx+/.style = {xshift=1 mm},
sy+/.style = {yshift=1 mm},
sx-/.style = {xshift=-1 mm},
sy-/.style = {yshift=-1 mm},
                    ]
\node[state] (A) {A};
\node[state] (B) [right=of A] {B};
\node[state] (C) [below=of A] {C};
\node[state] (D) [right=of C] {D};
%
\path[->]   ([sy+] A.east)  edge ["e"] ([sy+] B.west)
            ([sx+] B.south) edge       ([sx+] D.north)
            ([sy-] D.west)  edge       ([sy-] C.east)
            ([sx-] C.north) edge ["h"] ([sx-] A.south)
%
            ([sx+] A.south)  edge       ([sx+] C.north)
            ([sy+] C.east)   edge       ([sy+] D.west)
            ([sx-] D.north) edge ["g"]  ([sx-] B.south)
            ([sy-] B.west)  edge ["f"]  ([sy-] A.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Added nicer arrows positions in second image

**Addendum:**
Version which doesn't follow to image shown in question but to code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, calc, positioning, quotes}
\begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten < =  1mm, shorten > = 1mm,
node distance = 22mm, on grid, auto,
every path/.style = {-Latex},
state/.append style = {draw=pink!30!black, fill=pink!30, minimum size=8mm},
sx+/.style = {xshift=1 mm},
sy+/.style = {yshift=1 mm},
sx-/.style = {xshift=-1 mm},
sy-/.style = {yshift=-1 mm},
                    ]
\node[state] (A) {A};
\node[state] (B) [right=of A] {B};
\node[state] (C) [below right=of A] {C};
\node[state] (D) [right=of C] {D};
%
\path[->]   ([sy+] A.east)  edge ["e"] ([sy+] B.west)
            ([sx+] B.south east) edge       ([sx+] D.north west)
            ([sy-] D.west)  edge       ([sy-] C.east)
            ([sx-] C.north west) edge ["h"] ([sx-] A.south east)
%
            ([sx+] A.south east)  edge       ([sx+] C.north west)
            ([sy+] C.east)   edge       ([sy+] D.west)
            ([sx-] D.north west) edge ["g"]  ([sx-] B.south east)
            ([sy-] B.west)  edge ["f"]  ([sy-] A.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer. It utilizes beamer not other kind of styles such article or standalone.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand*{\arrowsep}{0.2cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my arrow/.style={-latex, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt},
                        shift left/.style={transform canvas={xshift = -\arrowsep/2}},
                        shift right/.style={transform canvas={xshift = \arrowsep/2}},
                        shift up/.style={transform canvas={yshift = \arrowsep/2}},
                        shift down/.style={transform canvas={yshift = -\arrowsep/2}},
                        node distance = 8.1 mm and 6 mm, > = stealth', my node/.style = {circle, draw=pink!30!black, fill=pink!30, minimum size=8mm}]
        \node[my node] (A) {\tiny A};
        \node[my node] (C) [below right=of A] {{\tiny C}};
        \node[my node] (B) [above right=of C] {{\tiny B}};
        \node[my node] (D) [below right=of B] {{\tiny D}};
        \draw (A) edge[my arrow, shift up,"e"]   (B) edge[my arrow, shift right] (C)
        (B) edge[my arrow, shift down,"f"] (A) edge[my arrow, shift left]  (D)
        (D) edge[my arrow, shift down] (C) edge[my arrow, shift right,"g",auto=right] (B)
        (C) edge[my arrow, shift up]   (D) edge[my arrow, shift left,"h"] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note the `transform canvas` for shifting the `edge`s, normal shifting does not work in this situations: see [TikZ: xshift not shifting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180665/114143)

A `\arrowsep` command is defined to hold the value of the styles `shift up`, `down`, `left` and `right`.

The keys `shorten >=<dim>` and `shorten <=<dim>` shortens the first and last bits of the path by `<dim>`, distancing the arrow from the nodes.

[image]

Comment: Where is beamer in the answer?! Yes you did generate the picture but you didn't show how to run it in or upload it in beamer.

Comment: "but isn't it just change the class?" Have you tried that? You will see that the code need to be modified properly to fit in beamer. The answer is then No it is not merely changing the class.

Comment: You need to modify your answer to reflect this change.

Comment: @CroCo It's trivial to export it as pdf and include it in beamer. The problem lies in the OP.

Comment: @c.p., Export to PDF?? As simple as that may be there's no need for it, it works with beamer just fine. The exceptional change needed was just to load `tikz`...

Comment: @CroCo, the TikZ picture is independent from document class. With other words, image is the same in `beamer`, `article`, ... `standalone`. Specific to used document class is only a size of the paper on which the images is drawn.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Well, I'm actually defending your point by telling what I would do (and what I actually do by producing figures for papers and then loading them for talks). Sure, it's not the shortest and optimal way, but I rather wanted to show that it is irrelevant whether `beamer` is loaded.

Comment: @c.p., I know, and good point, a simple workaround that works for many problems. I just don't want anyone getting the idea that the code does not work on `beamer` `:)`, @Zarko's point closes the deal on that one.

Comment: @CroCo As we are all here on a purely voluntarily basis, I don't think you are in a position to order someone to do something.

Comment: @samcarter, I'm not ordering anyone to do anything. I'm suggesting to address the problem which has been stated clearly in the title.

Comment: Some people state "It's trivial". This is true for people who have experience with Latex but we should not generalize this assumption.